How can i fix this error? When i trying to debugging on android emulator this error comes out
Even i tried flutter clean
pub get
cache clean it's not working at all.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\dev\last_try\last_try\android\build.gradle' line: 9

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

If anyone know how to fix this help me

Can you share your build.gradle file and what are the gradle and AGP versions you have?
